# processing large JSON without root element (Ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, bash, streaming

I am fairly new to ruby, so the question might be vary basic.

I am looking for a ruby library that will help me parse a large JSON file (of the order of 100 MBs)

The peculiarity of this JSON file is, it is created by a set of processes, and has no root element. Imagine the file looks like this

```
//this is element 1
{
    "name":"person 1",
    "dresses":[{"type":"pants","color":"green"},{"type":"shirt","color":"green"},{"type":"t-shirt","color":"green"}],
    "age":"34"
}
//this is element 2
{
    "name":"person 2",
    "dresses":[{"type":"pants","color":"blue"},{"type":"shirt","color":"red"}],
    "age":"33"

}
```

Since there is a lot of such elements(around 3M), I need to find a way so that I can get some elements at a time,or treat the input like a stream if possible, and write **each of the elements** to a text file after some processing based on values, just like

- A guy of age 34 does have three clothes, including a pair of green
  pants
- A guy of age 33 has two clothes, and no t-shirt

Basically, it is almost like parsing XML using sax parser, **but without a root element**. Can you please suggest a good ruby library to do the work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those are strings and you are only poping a few at a time, you can simply use JSON.parse.

For example:

```
a = '{
    "name":"person 1",
    "dresses":[{"type":"pants","color":"green"},{"type":"shirt","color":"green"},{"type":"t-shirt","color":"green"}],
    "age":"34"
}'
b = JSON.parse(a)
b['name'] 
=> 'person 1'
```

or if you prefer symbols(I do!)

```
b = JSON.parse(a).deep_symbolize_keys!
b[:name]
=> 'person 1'
```

If you really want a SAX like machine, this is a experimental gem: https://github.com/brianmario/json-machine

Comment: thanks for the gem. The file comes in lines rather than one string per element. What I did was alter the files . But if it were strings, I would prefer the approach outlined here.